# ExtJS Table Layout not displaying fieldlabels or adding padding

Tags: forms, extjs

I have a form which has a number of different fields and ultimately will become a dynamic formPanel.

I've opted for the table layout since it's easier to lay out the components but for some reason, the defaults settings are not applying and no field Labels are being displayed for any fields.

I've set out the configuration like:

```
SearchForm = Ext.extend(Ext.FormPanel, {
 id: 'myForm'
 ,title: 'Search Form'
 ,frame:true     
 ,waitMessage: 'Please wait.'
 ,labelWidth:80,
 buttonAlign:'center'
 ,initComponent: function() {    
     var config = {                 
        items: [{
            layout:{
                type:'table',
                columns:5
            },
            defaults:{
                //width:150,
                bodyStyle:'padding:20px'
            },               
                items:[{
                        xtype: 'label',
                        name: 'dateLabel',
                        cls: 'f',
                        text: "Required:"                   
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'datefield',
                        fieldLabel: "From Date",  
                        value: yesterday,
                        width: 110,
                        id: 'date1'                                             
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'datefield',
                        fieldLabel: "To Date",                      
                        id: 'date2',
                        width: 110,
                        value: yesterday                    

            },
            {
                xtype: 'displayfield', value: '  ',
                height:12,
                colspan:2
                }

            ],
            buttons: [{
                text: 'Submit',
                id: "submitBtn",                    
                handler: this.submit,
                scope: this

            },{
                text: 'Reset',
                id: "resetBtn",
                handler: this.reset,
                scope: this                     
            }
            ] 
        }]};

        // apply config
        Ext.apply(this, config);
        Ext.apply(this.initialConfig, config);

        SearchForm.superclass.initComponent.apply(this, arguments);


    }


});
```

Comment: What source of class 'f'

Comment: It's a css class that's taken from another file: .f{   
   font-size: 10pt;
   font-weight: bold;
   }

Comment: what it the code. Try to remove it and see if it's helped

Comment: it makes no difference. it is the fieldLabel in the dateField that is not being displayed. I need to make the table Layout cells bigger but the styling in the defaults is not working.

Comment: Please update all code . Missing brackets at the end

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is because you're defining the layout to be `table`, hence ExtJS not rendering the labels of fields correctly.

In each column, wrap your fields with an `Ext.Container` and give the panel a layout of `form`. That will tell ExtJS to render the labels correctly.

Comment: Don't use Ext.Panel unless you need toolbars or a title. Ext.Container should be used.